# Meteor: Listen for socket.io emit, then call Meteor function?

Tags: javascript, sockets, meteor, websocket, socket.io

I have socket.io emitting a message to the console containing an attribute and its value, in a format like this: `groupName - VALUE_HERE`.

I also have a Meteor function (seen below) that I'd like to call when the console message from Meteor is received. How can I accomplish this?

```
fireGroup = function(display, file) {
    console.log(display + ' - ' + file)
    if (display == "group") {
        var groupToFire = DisplayGroups.find({
            "groupName": file
        }).fetch();
        groupToFire.forEach(function(item, position) {
            var existing = DisplayContent.find({
                display: item.displayName
            }).fetch()[0];
            if (existing) {
                DisplayContent.update({
                    _id: existing._id
                }, {
                    $set: {
                        content: item.fileName,
                        display: item.displayName,
                        clickActive: item.clickActive,
                        groupForClick: item.groupForClick
                    }
                });
            } else {
                DisplayContent.insert({
                    display: item.displayName,
                    content: item.fileName,
                    clickActive: item.clickActive,
                    groupForClick: item.groupForClick
                });
            }
            if (item.displayName == 'concept') {
                Meteor.call("changeConcept", item.fileName);
            }
        });
    } else {

    }
};
```

Comment: I hate to start by asking why are you doing this, but "why are you doing this?" Meteor offers an awesome way to do 2 way data updates in quasi real time. It does use websockets to do this magic. Why would you want to use an extra layer of complexity and spin your own websocket communication within Meteor? Use the Meteor available functionalities: Collections, Methods etc...

Comment: @MrE Could you explain how to get Meteor to listen to the console updates?

Comment: are you talking about the javascript `console` ? This is meant for debugging. Not sure to understand what you are doing with that. Can you please explain?

Comment: Nevermind, forget the console comment. I'm working on a demo, none of this has to be about efficiency or best practices. I simply need to know how to get Meteor to listen to socket.io emits.

Comment: if you really want to use socket.io, then consider meteor as your nodejs server and deal with sockets as you would in node. i have not used socket.io so i cannot help with the details. I believe their doc has several examples.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.